# How to expose the asynchronous soap web services in mulesoft using cxf

Tags: web-services, mule, cxf

I have exposed the soap web services using the cxf in mulesoft and this is my interface and java code.

Interface is:

```
@WebService
public interface HelloWorld {
 String sayHi(String text);
 }
```

The java class is:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "demo.HelloWorld",
serviceName = "HelloWorld")
 public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
   public String sayHi(String text) {
  /*
   Here i am writing the logic which is takes the 15 seconds
   and i do not want that caller webservices must be wait to finish
   this process.

  */

return "Hello " + text;
  }
}
```

The currently the caller is waiting for finishing the all logic in the
sayHI() method but i want to do in asynchronous way its means the sayHi() method continuous the process and caller is not wait for response. So any idea how i can achieve in mulesoft?.

This is an reference in mule soft:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/building-web-services-with-cxf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you considered using **flow processing strategy** and **tuning your threads** ? :

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/flow-processing-strategies 
>   https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-fundamentals/v/3.7/flows-and-subflows 
>   http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/asynchronous-message-processing-with-mule/

and in the flow you can also use block after your Http listener for making it asynchronous :-

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/async-scope-reference

Comment: I added the Async component and inside i kept the java component and now its working. Thanks for response.